# Does Windows 7 have lower latencies than Windows 10 in gaming workflows?

Tags: computers, software

I saw a claim that Windows 7 is superior to Windows 10 for gaming:

> There’s a lot of reasons win7 is utilized. Especially in strictly
> competitive games that support it, (CSGO, Valorant, Fortnite), a lot
> of the time it’s a superior option due to lower latency and sometimes
> even better 0.1/1% lows depending on configuration, which are much
> more important than average FPS in those games. (Anyone can test this
> through CapFrameX and MLC.)

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/nxm9kl/support_plan_for_windows_7_and_windows_881/h1fmnd4

I cannot find much evidence in support of this though. These results seem to have been refuted: http://www.lofibucket.com/articles/dwm_latency.html

And this video shows Windows 10 running faster than Windows 7, at least in some games: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8rotnrhTuc

But maybe there are intricacies I am missing. So, is Windows 7 better than Windows 10 for gaming?

Comment: I apologise for the down-vote, it was quite accidental, and I'll reverse it if you make any edits (else it's too late at present, the system won't let me). Welcome to Skeptics.

Comment: Note that they don't claim that Windows 7 is faster overall but that it has minimal speed (better lows). That seems plausible to me. Windows 10 might be faster on average but it happens much more often, that it wants to download some update or reconfigure something internally or whatever and whenever this happens Win10 drains resources from the user processes and has miserable minimal speed. Essentially, occasionally Win10 is just busy with itself and doesn't have time for the end user. Comment instead of answer because totally unsourced and just personal impression.

Comment: Is a claim that -11 votes on Reddit really considered notable?

Comment: I think that on the subject it will be very difficult to find an unbiased (either way) source.

Comment: It looks like original comment you quoted here was deleted on reddit, so this doesn't seem to be a notable claim at this point. You may want to [re]ask this question as such on https://superuser.com/ (SE), for example.

Comment: I would doubt Win10 having more latency. But different operative systems do run different services and running services would take part in performance in edge cases. IMHO both services stripped OS's Win10 should be faster because of more optimized drivers. Note that this comment is related with @quarague's one